# FTP upload on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: aws, ftp, upload

We have our REST API running on AWS Elastic Beanstalk (NodeJS/Linux), there are some legacy devices that their only way to communicate with the world is uploading a file using FTP.

These devices would upload a file to FTP(s)://ftp.example.com, the file is processed generating some output (updates stuff using the API), then stored to S3

So I was thinking about this setup:

- EC2 instance running a custom *upload-only* FTP server (looked at [this one but seems outdated](https://github.com/nodeftpd/nodeftpd))
- This instance makes the file processing, saves it to S3 and then calls the existing API so it does some other stuff
- Hosted zone (in Route53) routes the ftp.example.com traffic to the EC2 instance

*Upload only* means that the device won't need other features like listing or downloading files.

Is this setup viable?, I haven't started coding/configuring it, and some of my assumptions may be infeasible, especially regarding the "FTP server" and routing that protocol in Route53

Comment: you may want to check this out as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32378176/476048

Answer (score -2):

This setup is possible. You can create an A- Record to point your domain to EC2. Please follow this link : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-ec2-instance.html

Comment: What about active/passive transmission? How will the EC2 instance be able to open new ports without AWS knowing?

Comment: You can have some pre-defined inbound/outbound rules applied to security groups and attach that security group to your EC2 container.